# Data point values listed as 'OTHER' in rendered charts, but Table shows expected values

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I've been working with App Insights Analytics chart tooling and noticed that a sizable portion of rendered chart data points have a listed value of 'OTHER'.  However, when I look at the Table data all columns and data points contain the expected values.

Is this some sort of trimming feature used when rendering charts?  If so, is there a way I can modify it?  Looking at fiddler while testing I don't see my app creating any malformed requests or firing requests I don't recognize.

Here's an image of the chart with the 'OTHER' values for the `name` and `url` fields: [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goB1c.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is something done by the various charts because with enough data, especially something circular, any more than a few values is just going to be an indistinguishable mess.  At some point, with enough distinct values, the math will start to break down to sub pixel values, and the items will overlap and be completely useless.

If you don't want to see the "OTHER" items, then you'll have to filter your data before the chart does, by using `limit` or `top` or `top-nested` or other various things.